# How can I reference the vectors directly and not the list in a nested lapply function?

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors:

```
this_list <- list(a <- c("this one","that one","these two"),b <- c("those some","heres more","two plus this","and one last one"),c <- c("the final one","it ends here"))
search words <- c("one","two")
```

I want to search the vectors in each element of the list for each/any keywords. I only care if a keyword appears, not which keyword.

```
lapply(search_words,grepl,lapply(this_list$,'['))
lapply(search_words,grepl,this_list'a')
```

These will tell me, respectively, if a list element has a keyword and if a vector element has a keyword, by keyword.

I want to have a function that at once search per list element, per vector element if a keyword is in there.
sample desired output:

```
this_list a
search_word "one"
true    true    false
search word "two
false    false    true

this_list b
search_word "one"
false   false   false   true
```

Even better would be to not breakdown by search_word and just tell me, by list element, if a search word was found in the vectors

```
this_list  'a'
true    true    true
this_list 'b'
false    false   true  true
...
```

Comment: Can you please include real working R code? `search words <- c("one","two")` and `this_list'a'` are not, and while *that* is easy to brush off and fix, it is easy to wonder if problems your experiencing are due to typos like these or something else. Said differently: *please test your own code* in a fresh R instance. This will fix things like undefined objects and typos.

Answer (score 1):

```r
sapply(this_list, function(L) 
  sapply(search_words, grepl, x = L, simplify = FALSE),
  simplify = FALSE)
# $a
# $a$one
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# $a$two
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# $b
# $b$one
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# $b$two
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# $c
# $c$one
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
# $c$two
# [1] FALSE FALSE
```

or

```r
sapply(this_list, function(L)
  rowSums(sapply(search_words, grepl, x = L, simplify = TRUE)) > 0, 
  simplify = FALSE)
# $a
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
# $b
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# $c
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

---

FYI, never use `<-` inside of a function call like `list`.

```r
this_list <- list(a <- ..., b <- ...)
```

This doesn't name the entries in `this_list`, it produces objects in the current environment named `a` and `b`, and puts the contents of those objects into the list without names.

Instead, always use `=` inside of function calls (unless your intent is to create an object and use the object's contents only, disregarding the name ... this is valid use, but much less common.)

```r
this_list <- list(a = ..., b = ...)
```

---

Data

```r
this_list <- list(a = c("this one","that one","these two"),b = c("those some","heres more","two plus this","and one last one"),c = c("the final one","it ends here"))
search_words <- c("one","two")
```

Comment: Slight variation on #2 - `lapply(this_list, \(tl) do.call(\`|\`, lapply(search_words, \(sw) grepl(sw,tl))) )` to avoid simplification.